# disable href after 1 click on html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the `href` to be disabled after 1 click, can it be done using javascript or jquery?

Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns ="http://www.w3.org 1999 xhtml" xml :lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>

     a:link{
       color:#1DAAA1;
     }

     a:visited{
       color:green;
     }

     a:hover{
       background: #ff0000;
       color: #FFF;
     }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table width="500" align="center" border="5px solid">
      <tr align="center" >
        <td><a href="http://www.google.com.my/" onclick="return false"> Google </a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/"> Yahoo </a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.bing.com/"> Bing </a></td>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"> Wikipedia </a></td>
        <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"> Facebook </a></td>                         
     </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: for jQuery, have a look at [.removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Comment: Hi find the new answer...hope it will do the needful :)

Comment: What does 'disabled' mean? Unclickable?

Comment: yes,unclickable after 1 click once or visited once

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Pure javascript solution:

```
<script> 
   function clickAndDisable(link) {
     // disable subsequent clicks
     link.onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
     }
   }   
</script>
<a href="target.html" onclick="clickAndDisable(this);">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

This is simpler approach using *jQuery* that prevents links double clicking: no `onclick` attributes, `id` isn't required, no `href` removing.

```
$("a").click(function (event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    $(this).addClass("disabled");
});
```

**Tip:** you can use any selector (like `button`, `input[type='submit']`, etc.) and it will work.

Comment: Perfect solution, can I exclude links?

Comment: MrPHP, yep, you can use any selector you want, e.g. instead of `$("a")` use `$("button")`

Comment: for me: does nothing in jquery 3.4.1

Answer (score 5):

just try this....

```
a:visited {
 color:green;
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default; 
}
```

Comment: [`Warning: The use of pointer-events in CSS for non-SVG elements is experimental.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: Still, +1 for a creative solution using one of the lesser known CSS properties.

Comment: @JanDvorak: thanks for +1.. hope i come with better one soon :)

Comment: its not working,i can still go to visited page...the visited link must be disabled completely after clicked once

Answer (score 4):

Pure JavaScript solution to allow user to follow the URL only once:

```
<a id="elementId" 
   href="www.example.com" 
   onclick="setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('elementId').removeAttribute('href');}, 1);"
   >Clik and forget</a>
```

Once clicked, this will remove the href attribute (with 1 ms wait to allow the original action to start) making the link silent. Similar as suggested by Dineshkani, but the original answer caused action to not to start at all on some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

this time i tried it with Javascript... hope it will help u:) just call the below function in "onclick()" of the required href tags...

```
​function check(link) {
    if (link.className != "visited") {
       //alert("new");
       link.className = "visited";
       return true;     
    }
    //alert("old");
    return false;
}​​
```

like ​`<a href="#" onclick="return check(this);">link here</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`
and see demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p5BRT/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do with jquery

```
<a href='http://somepage.com' id='get' onlick='$("#"+this.id).attr("href","")'>Something to be go </a>
```

Or with the javascript

```
<a href='http://somepage.com' id='get' onlick='document.getElementById(this.id).removeAttribute("href");'>Something to be go </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ayyappan Sekar's answer, I have just done something very similar using jQuery:

```
$('#yourId').click(function (e) {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('visited'))
    {
        $(this).addClass('visited')
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).removeAttr("href"); // optional
        // some other code here
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

duplicate the same div in html and css, the duplicated one must be below the original one using: z-index=-1 or/and position:absolute.

make the original div onclick="HideMe(this)"

```
JS:
<script type="text/javascript">
function HideMe(element){
element.style.display='none';
}
</script>
```

it might be not the best way, but 100% goal achievable.

Comment: remember: the duplicated div/anchor mustn't include the href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I want to leave here an example that works with Knockout.js that I used with IFrame, but as IFrame doesnt work with local files, I made this example with divs.
When you click the link, the function is called, as you can see with the `alert()`commented inside, but when you dial something in the input dialog and click again the link, the div is not updated by the Knockout.js, only if you click the other link that calls the same function but with diferent parameter.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:fAlter(2)">Page 2</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:fAlter(3)">Page 3</a>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="bindHTML: dados"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           function myPage2(nPage) {
               var cPage = '<div>Pagina 2</div>';
               if (nPage == 3) { cPage = '<div>Pagina 3</div>' }
               cPage += '<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">';
               //alert('clicked!');
               return cPage
           }
           var viewModel =  {
                dados : ko.observable()
           }
           ko.bindingHandlers.bindHTML = {
                init: function () {
                     // Prevent binding on the dynamically-injected HTML (as developers are unlikely to expect that, and it has security implications)
                     return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };
           },
                update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                     // setHtml will unwrap the value if needed
                     ko.utils.setHtml(element, valueAccessor());
                     var elementsToAdd = element.children;
                     for (var i = 0; i < elementsToAdd.length; i++) {
                          ko.cleanNode(elementsToAdd[i]); //Clean node from Knockout bindings
                          ko.applyBindings(bindingContext, elementsToAdd[i]);
                     }
                }
           };
           ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
           viewModel.dados(myPage2(2));
           function fAlter(nPage) {
               viewModel.dados(myPage2(nPage));
           }
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vanilla JS approach.

You can simply drop in this code and add the `js-click-once` class to your links/buttons. It also adds a `disabled` class to the link/button.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".js-click-once").forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (el.classList.contains('disabled')) {
            el.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        el.classList.add("disabled");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**jQuery solution:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns ="http://www.w3.org 1999 xhtml" xml :lang="en">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function check(link) {
                $(link).replaceWith($(link).text());
            }
        </script>
        <style>

            a:link{
                color:#1DAAA1;

            }
            a:visited{
                color:green;
            }
            a:hover{
                background: #ff0000;
                color: #FFF;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <table width="500" align="center" border="5px solid">
            <tr align="center" >
                <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" onclick="return check(this);"> Google </a></td>
                <td><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank" onclick="return check(this);"> Yahoo </a></td>
                <td><a href="http://www.bing.com" target="_blank" onclick="return check(this);"> Bing </a></td>
                <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org" target="_blank" onclick="return check(this);"> Wikipedia </a></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you use jQuery for this and not even bind events?

Comment: @StephanMuller: I want the href to be disabled after 1 click, can it be done using javascript or jquery? - It's clear in question.

Comment: its useful but still can visit after reload/refreshing the page