# I want to get url from the same document using JS onclick method

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get url from some links. If I click on the google link, output should be google.com and for other links should be the same. But I don't know how to do that. Sorry I'm too new to programming. Help me out please.Thank you
My code is here, please guide me well for this task. Thanks again...`

```js
<script>
function get_url() {
    document.getElementById("field1").value = document.getElementById("url").value;
}
</script>
```

```html
<a onclick="get_url()" target = "_blank" id = "url"  href="http://www.google.com/">Google </a> <br/>
<a onclick="get_url()" target = "_blank" id = "url" href="http://www.facebook.com/">Facebook </a><br/>
<a onclick="get_url()" target = "_blank" id = "url" href="http://www.twitter.com/">Twitter </a><br/>
<a onclick="get_url()" target = "_blank" id = "url" href="http://www.youtube.com/">Youtube </a><br/><br/>

URL : <input type="text" id="field1"><br><br>

<p>Click on the link above to get the URL of the linked document.</p>
```

Comment: for the scenario explained by you. The Id should be unique so easy for identify

Comment: @RohitPoudel Thanks much! It's working now!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there - there were just a few issues.

Firstly, you can't have multiple elements with the same ID.  IDs should be unique, but you don't actually need them in this instance.  Instead I changed it to pass the link into `get_url()` as a parameter, and then used that to get the href value and insert it into the text box.

Finally, I added `return false;` to the function, in order to stop the links actually triggering a page change.

```js
function get_url(link) {
    document.getElementById("field1").value = link.href;
    return false;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="get_url(this)" target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/">Google </a> <br/>
<a onclick="get_url(this)" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/">Facebook </a><br/>
<a onclick="get_url(this)" target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com/">Twitter </a><br/>
<a onclick="get_url(this)" target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/">Youtube </a><br/><br/>

URL : <input type="text" id="field1"><br><br>

<p>Click on the link above to get the URL of the linked document.</p>
```

Comment: Idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580815/disable-href-after-1-click-on-html

Comment: @daremachine Good point out there, but `return false;` is 100% browser compatible, and I also think it's a lot clearer than that example.

Comment: Agree 100% with you, I wanted give point about pass 'this' as function parameter which is doing what OP need.